# Managing licenses for Office 365 in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, powershell, office365

I am trying to run Office365 cmdlets in a vb.net webservice project.The code is:

```
Public Function ExcutePowershellCommands() As ObjectModel.Collection(Of PSObject)
    Try            
        Dim userList As ObjectModel.Collection(Of PSObject) = Nothing

        Dim initialSession As InitialSessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()
        initialSession.ImportPSModule(New String() {"MSOnline"})

        Dim O365Password_secureString As New System.Security.SecureString()
        Dim O365Password As String = "password"
        For Each x As Char In O365Password
            O365Password_secureString.AppendChar(x)
        Next
        Dim credential As New PSCredential("username", O365Password_secureString)

        Dim connectCommand As New Command("Connect-MsolService")
        connectCommand.Parameters.Add((New CommandParameter("Credential", credential)))

        Dim getCommand As New Command("Get-MsolUser")

        Using psRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSession)

            psRunSpace.Open()


            For Each com As Command In New Command() {connectCommand, getCommand}
                Dim pipe As Pipeline = psRunSpace.CreatePipeline()
                pipe.Commands.Add(com)

                Dim results As ObjectModel.Collection(Of PSObject) = pipe.Invoke()
                Dim [error] As ObjectModel.Collection(Of Object) = pipe.[Error].ReadToEnd()
                If [error].Count > 0 AndAlso com.Equals(connectCommand) Then
                    Throw New ApplicationException("Problem in login! " + [error](0).ToString())
                    Return Nothing
                End If
                If [error].Count > 0 AndAlso com.Equals(getCommand) Then
                    Throw New ApplicationException("Problem in getting data! " + [error](0).ToString())
                    Return Nothing
                Else
                    userList = results
                End If
            Next

            psRunSpace.Close()
        End Using
        Return userList
    Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
        Throw
    End Try
End Function
```

When Connect-MsolService is run, I get this error message:

> There was no endpoint listening at https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/provisioningwebservice.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

I can run this function successfully within a windows App. I think some thing might be wrong in IIS. any idea?

Comment: Hi.. found any soln? If yes, kindly share here.

Comment: Not yet unfortunately. That project has gone on hold so I have not worked on it anymore.